# Criar uma "tarja com opacidade" em cima de um <tr>

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma tabela gerada dinamicamente:

[image: painel]

---

Gostaria de criar **uma classe no CSS** que fizesse uma "camada" por cima, com transparência.

Exemplo:

[image: tarja]

---

Se eu usar o `background-color`, ele só irá mudar o fundo, então teria que ser algo por cima. Então não serviria.

*O código da tabela é básico, são `<tr>` e `<td>`, então não faz diferença postar o código dela.*

Comment: Pintar o background e mexer na opacity da tr talvez dê um resultado muito semelhante. Já tentou?

Comment: Então, mas só muda o fundo, os elementos ficam por cima como eu disse sobre o `background-color`... a não ser que seja outra forma, e/ou tenha como "subir" o background do `<tr>` em cima dos `<td>`. 

Comment: Mas você mexeu também na opacidade da `<tr>`? Reduzindo a opacidade, tanto o fundo quanto o conteúdo vão ficar com transparência, talvez fique próximo do resultado que você quer.

Comment: @bfavaretto Acho que é o que o hugocsl respondeu... acho que era essa `position: absolute;` que manda pra frente! Agradecido! ✌️

Comment: Sim, a resposta dele é o melhor caminho. Talvez seja o mais genérico possível. Só acho que não funciona sem border-collapse na tabela.

Comment: @bfavaretto realmente ele fugiu da `<tr>`...

Comment: @bfavaretto isso mesmo, se deixar o collapse da borda fica um espaço em brando entre uma célula e outra....

Comment: @bfavaretto consegui fazer sem precisar clocar o border-collapse na table :), apesar de não ser muito elegante... Olha lá a opção 1 que editei na resposta.

Comment: Boa @hugocsl. Nesse caso gambiarra tá valendo, porque não é um problema trivial (como você sabe, não pode violar a sintaxe HTML das tabelas).

Comment: Uma forma usando JS: https://jsfiddle.net/zd3uwgsh/7/

Comment: @sam Dessa forma você criou um `<spam>` por cima do `<tr>`, e assim não preciso nem alterar o CSS, somente adicionar a classe na `<tr>` que eu preciso por a tarja, seria isso?

Comment: Quase isso. Apenas tem a classe `.overlay` que precisa colocar no CSS, mas se não quiser mexer no CSS pode colocar as propriedades diretamente inline no span pelo JS. Como os spans tem posição e altura fixa, caso queira que seja responsivo, é preciso adicionar mais uns códigos, mas isso não seria problema.

Comment: Mas no geral é isso mesmo, basta colocar a classe .tarja na tr que vc quer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Opção 1:**

Nessa opção vc coloca um `box-shadow: inset` bem grande na TR, e coloca position:relative nas TD para poder colocar um `z-index:-1` nelas e jogar pra traz da sombra da TR. A intensão do `box-shadow` e não precisar setar `border-collapse` na `table` devido ao seu framework.

```css
.tab {
    width: 100%;
}
.tab tr.ativa  {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
.tab tr td  {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative; 
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<table class="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <item>1</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>2</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>3</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>4</item>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ativa">
        <td>
            <item>a</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>s</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>d</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>f</item>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <item>a</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>s</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>d</item>
        </td>
        <td>
            <item>f</item>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Opção 2:**

Solução e criando um `::after` nas `tds` e no hover na `tr` vc mostra o `::after`. Veja que ele está por cima do conteúdo como vc queria.

```css
.tab {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tab td {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.tab tr:hover td::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;  
}
.tab tr.ativa td::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;  
}
```

```html
<table class="tab">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <item>1</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>2</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>3</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>4</item>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ativa">
    <td>
      <item>a</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>s</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>d</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>f</item>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <item>a</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>s</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>d</item>
    </td>
    <td>
      <item>f</item>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Mas dessa forma ele ficaria em todos ao passar o ponteiro, não é? Se for, não seria isso. Eu preciso que fique fixo. Pois serão alguns que terão essa tarja. E aí a ideia por uma classe, assim eu consigo colocar ou não dinamicamente.

Comment: @RBZ Não, só vai ficar sobre a TR que vc passar o mouse. Veja na edição que fiz na resposta que inclui mais uma TR. Entendi vou editar novamelte

Comment: @RBZ editei novamente, agora repare que a TR com a classe .ativa fica vermelha direto, mesmo sem o mouse nela.

Comment: Isso! Exatamente! .. Só uma dúvida, tenho que manter o `tr:hover td::after`? Ou posso só fazer o `tr.ativa td::after`?

Comment: @RBZ pode retirar esse classe tranquilamente. e cloque a classe ativa na TR que quiser. Ou comente o CSS vai que vc precisa depois...

Comment: Cara, não funcionou. Ele começa a tarja no início da página. O maior problema é que uso framework, então preciso criar uma classe no final, sem alterar o resto, se não afeta outras partes. [Materializecss](https://materializecss.com/)

Comment: @RBZ eu não entendi direito o problema, mas editei a resposta, agora eu coloquei a `class="tab"` na tabela e ajustei o CSS para atingir apenas os elementos dentro da tabela com a classe .tab

Comment: Agora aparentemente funcionou. Mas infelizmente ele está matando alguns elementos da table do framework... Teria que tratar 1 a 1 né?

Comment: Calma jovem, to pensando em uma gambeta aqui que acho que vai funciona já te falo. só um min

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80780/discussion-between-rbz-and-hugocsl).

Comment: Abri um chat, assim consigo te mandar print

Answer (score 2):

Acho que dessa forma vai pode te ajudar. E é bem simples:

```css
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
table{
background: #e0e0e0;
}
td{
border:none;
}

.red {
background: red;
opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td> Nº</td>
  <td> HORA</td>
  <td> Placa</td>
  <td> Tipo</td>
  <td> Tara</td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="red">
  <td> Nº</td>
  <td> HORA</td>
  <td> Placa</td>
  <td> Tipo</td>
  <td> Tara</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> Nº</td>
  <td> HORA</td>
  <td> Placa</td>
  <td> Tipo</td>
  <td> Tara</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Não está ficando por cima, mas funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Pode criar um elemento qualquer (um `div` por exemplo) dentro da `TD` para fazer isso:

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}

.tarja {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 10px;
  left: 10% ;
  margin: -12px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>texto qualquer</td>
    <td>
    texto qualquer
    <div class="tarja"></div>
    </td>
    <td>texto qualquer</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Usei `position` na `TD` e na `div` para facilitar o posicionamento dentro da `TD`, dai pode usar o tamanho em porcentagem e facilitar o posicionamento.

Comment: Posso usar a `<div>` pegando todos os `<td>`?

Comment: nesse exemplo tem q ter uma div por td :(

Comment:  ... é aí salgou demais! rs ... Vou testar as respostas aqui, ver qual aplica de forma mais simples no meu caso. Mas agradeço! ✌️

Comment: uma outra alternativa seria usar uma imagem que poderia ser posicionada no background da `td`

Comment: Mas aí ficaria atrás dos elementos, não é?